# How to solve the ball drawing problem?

Tags: probability, self-study

Suppose a basket contains $B$ blue balls and $R$ red balls. Then, suppose I pick $N$ balls from the basket. What is the probability that I get

1. At least $b$ blue ones and $r$ red ones
2. At least $b$ blue ones and exactly $r$ red ones
3. Exactly $b$ blue ones and exactly $r$ red ones

How does the solution differ if I put the balls back or don't?

I suppose this is a very basic problem in statistics so I attempted to cover a range of related problems here. I suppose I should know about permutations and combinations for solving this. (This is not a homework, I'm studying stats for fun.) What I am trying to learn here is how to solve *any* similar kind of problem.

Comment: The easiest way to learn this kind of stuff is to choose small numbers e.g. $B=2, R=3, N=4$ or maybe $N=6$ and make a _list_ of all possible outcomes for small values of $b$ and $r$. That will help you understand what things need to be considered in finding the answer in general.

Comment: The keywords are "binomial distribution" and "hypergeometric distribution".

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get "at least" ***b*** balls then I assume you want a 100% probability which means ***N*** should be equal to all ***r*** balls plus the number of ***b*** balls you've set as the minimum. This guarantees the minimum for ***b*** and you will also have exactly ***(N - minimum b) x r / (all balls)***.

When you draw a ball you statically get a fraction of each color, so ***N = (all b) /(total) + (all r) / (total)***.

It doesn't matter if you put the balls back from a statistical point of view - you will always have the same odds if you always have the same ball group. When you *don't* put the balls back then you have the chance of changing the probabilities but they still work by the same formula.

Comment: I believe you may have misinterpreted the question.  It is asking a *probability* problem rather than a statistical problem. For instance, with $N=1$, $B=50$, and $R=50$, the chance of getting at least $b=1$ blue balls and $r=0$ red balls is $50\%$. The correct answer will refer to binomial and hypergeometric distributions, as @Elvis indicated in a comment.

Comment: Thank you, I stand corrected. I did misinterpret the question.